# Is there any element of order $51$ in the group $U(103)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Does  there  exist  an  element  of  order  $51$  in  the  multiplicative  group  $U(103)$ ?

Now  if  the  element  exist  say $x$  then  it  satisfies  the  equation $$x^{51}\equiv 1\pmod {103}$$ . Now $103$  being  a  prime  it  is  clear  that  there  is an  element $y$ in  $U(n)$ satisfying  $$y^{102}\equiv 1\pmod {103}$$ 
So  exactly an  element  of  half  order is  required  to  be  found.

Is  there  any  result  in  number  theory that  might imply  that  $$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$ ensures  the  existence  of  some  $b$  such that $$b^{{p-1}\over {2}}\equiv {1}\pmod p$$  where  $p$  is  a  prime not  dividing  $a$

Comment: What's the order of $y^{2}$?

Comment: that  is  $51$. Thank  you.

Comment: Take $b=a^2$, and $a$ a generator of $U(103)$ (don't worry about the existence of $a$).

Comment: @Josh B : What is the order of $y^2$?

Comment: @Servaes :  In  the  link  you  posted ,  the  user   just  asked  a  question . In  my  post  I  have ,  although  the  same  problem,  attempted  something  on  my  own  and  asked  whether  that  method  is  correct  and  can  be  furthered  to  find  the  result .  Right $?$  .  Why  flag  it  as  _duplicate_  $?$

Comment: Because the question was asked and elaborately answered already. The answer to your particular question, fitting your particular approach, can also be found there.

Comment: Q: "Why flag it as duplicate?" A: "Because the answers to that question help here as well." While you try to work on the problem yourself (GOOD!!) with questions about orders of elements of groups it is equally important to show that no lower power of an element will be equal to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$103$ is a prime and so $U(103)$ has $103-1=102 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 17$ elements.

By Cauchy's theorem, $U(103)$ has an element $a$ of order $3$ and an element $b$ of order $17$.

Since $U(103)$ is abelian, $ab$ has order $3 \cdot 17=51$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $U(103)$ denotes the multiplicative group of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{103}$.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_{103}$ is a field;  the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic; and a cyclic group of order $n$ contains elements of order $d$ whenever $d$ divides $n$ (take the $\frac{n}{d}$-th power of a generator).

You can replace $103$ by some non-primes $n$, and still $U(n)$ remains cyclic.

Comment: If  I  replace 103  by  24  would  $U(24)$  be  cyclic ? @Yassine Guerboussa

Comment: No, $U(24)$ is elementary $2$-abelian of rank $3$ (a vector space of dim $3$ over the field with two elements).  In general, for an prime $p$, we have $U(p^n)$ is cyclic of order $(p-1)p^{n-1}$; and $U(2^n)$ is a product  of the cyclic group of order $2$ by the cyclic group of order $2^{n-2}$ (for $n\geq 3$).  You can find $U(n)$ easily from the decomposition of $n$ as a product of prime powers.

Answer (score 0):

I found that $2$ is an answer, but I just used mathematica, which might not be what you're looking for.

[image]

Note: also found $4,6,7,15$. Probably more.

Comment: There are $32=\phi(51)$ solutions, but $11$ is not one of them.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used Mathematica, so I might be slightly off, but I believe the following will tell you every answer: `Select[Range[2..102], AND[Mod[#^3,103]!=1,Mod[#^17,103]!=1,Mod[#^51,103]==1]&];`.